# Not able to print the elements of html in console using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am having a id and a text in the html page and I am trying to retrieve them in the javascript and print them in console
the code snippet

```js
const personArr = document.querySelectorAll(".person_name");
   personArr.forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click',() => {
    document.querySelector("#insertName").innerText = "";
    document.querySelector("#insertName").innerText = `${item.innerText}`;
    document.querySelector("#insertName").innerText =`${item.id}`;
    
  })
})
      var form = document.getElementById('msg_send_btn');

 form.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var input = document.getElementById("write_msg").value
        var id= document.getElementById("insertName").value
         console.log(input)
   console.log(id)
 }
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 3000px;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.inbox_people {
  background: #f8f8f8 none repeat scroll 0 0;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 40%;
  border-right: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}
.inbox_msg {
  border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.top_spac {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
}

.recent_heading {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
}
.srch_bar {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 60%;
  padding: ;
}
.headind_srch {
  padding: 10px 29px 10px 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
}

.recent_heading h4 {
  color: #05728f;
  font-size: 21px;
  margin: auto;
}
.srch_bar input {
  border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 0;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 2px 0 4px 6px;
  background: none;
}
.srch_bar .input-group-addon button {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  padding: 0;
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.srch_bar .input-group-addon {
  margin: 0 0 0 -27px;
}

.chat_ib h5 {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #464646;
  margin: 0 0 8px 0;
}
.chat_ib h5 span {
  font-size: 13px;
  float: right;
}
.chat_ib p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #989898;
  margin: auto;
}
.chat_img {
  float: left;
  width: 11%;
}
.chat_ib {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
  width: 88%;
}

.chat_people {
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}
.chat_list {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 18px 16px 10px;
}
.inbox_chat {
  height: 550px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.active_chat {
  background: #ebebeb;
}

.incoming_msg_img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 6%;
}
.received_msg {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 0 0 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 92%;
}
.received_withd_msg p {
  background: #ebebeb none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #646464;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
.time_date {
  color: #747474;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 8px 0 0;
}
.received_withd_msg {
  width: 57%;
}
.mesgs {
  float: left;
  padding: 30px 15px 0 25px;
  width: 60%;
}

.sent_msg p {
  background: #05728f none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
.outgoing_msg {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 26px 0 26px;
}
.sent_msg {
  float: right;
  width: 46%;
}
.input_msg_write input {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  color: #4c4c4c;
  font-size: 15px;
  min-height: 48px;
  width: 100%;
}

.type_msg {
  border-top: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
  position: relative;
}
#msg_send_btn {
  background: #05728f none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  height: 33px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 11px;
  width: 33px;
}
.messaging {
  padding: 0 0 50px 0;
}
.msg_history {
  height: 516px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">

  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

  <div class="container">
    <h3 class=" text-center">Messaging</h3>
    <div class="messaging">
      <div class="inbox_msg">
        <div class="inbox_people">
          <div class="headind_srch">
            <div class="recent_heading">
              <h4>Recent</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="srch_bar">
              <div class="stylish-input-group">
                <input type="text" class="search-bar" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                  <button type="button"> <i class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i> </button>
                </span> </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="inbox_chat">
            <div class="chat_list active_chat">
              <div class="chat_people">

                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5><a href="#" class="person_name" id="1">satya <span class="chat_date"></span></a></h5>
                  
                  <p></p>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat_list active_chat">
              <div class="chat_people">

                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5><a href="#" class="person_name" id="2">ferin <span class="chat_date"></span></a></h5>
                  
                  <p></p>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chat_list active_chat">
              <div class="chat_people">

                <div class="chat_ib">
                  <h5><a href="#" class="person_name" id="3">laxmi<span class="chat_date"></span></a></h5>
                  
                  <p></p>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="mesgs">
          <div class="msg_history">
            <p id="insertName"></p>
            <div class="type_msg">
              <div class="input_msg_write">
                <input type="text" id="write_msg" placeholder="Type a message" />
                <button id="msg_send_btn" type="button"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Here I am having three users at the left and when I click on one user the user id and and input box is displayed with a send button so here I want the text message and id when I click the send button in the console here I am getting text and undefined in the place of id can anyone help me out from this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you're trying to print the value of the id from a p.  The quickest way to fix this would be to change your button click event from:

```
form.onclick = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var input = document.getElementById("write_msg").value
      var id = document.getElementById("insertName").value
      console.log(input)
      console.log(id)
    }
```

to:

```
form.onclick = function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var input = document.getElementById("write_msg").value
      var id = document.getElementById("insertName").innerText;
      console.log(input)
      console.log(id)
    }
```